# How to evaluate limit of this function?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$ \lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x}{2x +1}\right)^x$$
Answer is $0$, or it's indeterminate? Can we use Second Remarkable Limit? Also, using L Hospitals rule is not permitted.

Comment: HINT: $0<\frac{x}{2x+1}<\frac12$ for $x>0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$\Big(\frac{x}{2x+1}\Big)^x=\frac{1}{2^x}\Big(\frac{1}{1+\frac{1/2}{x}}\Big)^x$

$\Big(1+\frac{1/2}{x}\Big)^x\xrightarrow{x\rightarrow\infty}e^{1/2}$

$\frac{1}{2^x}\xrightarrow{x\rightarrow\infty}0$

Comment: What if x -> -inf?

Comment: $(1-\frac{1}{2x})^{-x}\xrightarrow{x\rightarrow\infty}e^{1/2}$ and $\frac{1}{2^{-x}}\xrightarrow{x\rightarrow\infty}=\infty$

Comment: so, it's like this limit indeterminate in whole infinity space

Comment: @Mouvre: If you change your question to the analysis of $\lim_{|x|\rightarrow\infty}\Big(\frac{x}{2x+1}\Big)^{x}$, then of course, this limit does not exists, for when $x>0$ the target function approaches $0$ while if $x<0$, the target function diverges to $\infty$.